# curl command to add a value in a multi valued property of a particular node in CQ

Tags: curl, aem, crx

I have a paticular node for eg : /content/site/advisors/jcr:content which consists of a property "cq:allowed templates" whose value consists of  multiple  string values(array of strings) .I want to add another string value into it using a curl command.Please suggest.
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far ? Please share some code.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="stringProperty@TypeHint" value="String[]"/>

Answer (score 5):

The `@Patch` suffix is used by the Sling POST servlet to add or remove values from a multi-value property, for example:

```
$ curl -u admin:admin -Fmulti@TypeHint="String[]" -Fmulti=one -Fmulti=two -Fmulti=four http://localhost:8080/test
$ curl -u admin:admin -Fmulti@Patch="true" -Fmulti="+three" -Fmulti="-four" http://localhost:8080/test

$ curl http://localhost:8080/test.tidy.json
{
  "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
  "multi": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ]
  }
```

The docs are at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#patch

Answer (score 3):

Simply add multiple -Fproperty-name="property-value" with a additional TypeHint:

`-Fproperty-name@TypeHint="String[]" -Fproperty-name="first property value" -Fproperty-name="second property value"` etc.